# JButton Press (Not Release)

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I have a very small JButton called "b", which I want to do some things on click and not on release of it. I use the following code:

```
b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            //do some stuff
        }
    });
```

But what I realize is that it does the stuff I want as soon as the click is first pressed and then released. How can this be done my way?
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A click means that a button has been pressed and released. A click event is triggered when a button is clicked and only if the button is still armed(mouse within the bounds of the button) when mouse is released. To handle the **pressed** event, use the low-level `MouseListener`

```
btn.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        //do some stuff
    }

    /*Override other methods*/

});
```

Or better use a `MouseAdapter`

```
btn.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            //do some stuff
        }

        /*No need to override other methods, `MouseAdapter` already does it*/

    });
```

Comment: Although this answer is marked as the solution, it is not really the solution for the problem. I have it implemented like this, but I want to react on press/release of the button even if it is not toggled by mouse but by keyboard input. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Above answer does only react on mouse events, but it is possible to toggle a buttons pressed state by using space key when it has the input focus.
For a complete implementation, use MouseListener AND KeyListener.

```
b.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        doOnPressedAction();
    }
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        doOnReleasedAction();
    }
});
b.addKeyListener(new KeyListener(){
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (sendButton.getModel().isPressed()) {
            doOnPressedAction();
        } else {
            // just in case it can happen that the button is released on
            // a key press action (maybe another controls key listener...)
            doOnReleasedAction();
        }
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        doOnReleasedAction();
    }
});
```